# Bulk audio watermarking with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have about 10,000 audio files that I need to overlay with copyright sound. How can this be done with ffmpeg? Maybe there is a script for mass combining audio into one track?

If there is a simpler solution, I will be very grateful, since several days of googling did not lead to anything. Either I found programs without a job description, or solutions that only do one file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script for that depending your operating system. As I program with php, I would write a php CLI programme for this use case

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
// ensure ./new directory exists before running script
<?php
$dir = "/home/seb/Audio samples/";
$files1 = scandir($dir); //Get all the file from your $dir directory on your computer
foreach ($files1 as $myfile){
 $mystring = "ffmpeg -i $myfile ./new/$myfile"; //Write here your FFMPEG command you want in a string
 exec($mystring);
 }
?>
```

Comment: When I give addresses with URLs here, I am served myself, so I don't know what to do on this forum to help ....

Comment: <!-- language: c --><?php
 $files1 = scandir($dir); //Get all the file from your $dir directory on your computer
 foreach ($files1 as $myfile){
  $mystring = "ffmpeg -i $myfile ....."; //Write here your FFMPEG command you want in a string
  exec($mystring);
 }
?> ```

Comment: Use the `edit` link to edit the answer if I've got something wrong. I've never used `php`